# How to include any sub-catalogs when fetching a site's origin?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get the url of which a project runs in using this:

```
const url = window.location.origin;
```

It works but the problem I'm facing that any sub-catalogs aren't picked up. So when I run it for `https://my-app.com/ui` for example only `https://my-app.com` is picked up.

`https://my-app.com` points to `https://my-app.com/ui` and that's also where my app runs.

Only solution I can think of is to split the `window.location.pathname` but that will break when the origin isn't using any sub-catalogs, such as `http:localhost:4200` or `https://dev.myApp.com`.

How can I modify the code above to also include the sub-catalogs so that it works for all the above scenarios?

**EDIT:**

I'm on Angular 5, so perhaps there is an Angular way?

Expected outputs for given urls:

```
https://myApp.com/ui/dashboard/events -> https://myApp.com/ui 
http://localhost:4200 -> http://localhost:4200 
https://sites.dev.myApp.com/ui2/dashboard/events -> https://sites.dev.myApp.com/ui2 
https://sites.dev.myApp.com/ui2/app/dashboard/events -> shttps://ites.dev.myApp.com/ui2/app/dashboard/events
```

Comment: What is the expected output for both scenarios?  `https://my-app.com/ui` and `https://my-app.com/`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take the `origin` and first value before `/` from `pathname`

```
var output = location.origin + ( location.pathname ? location.pathname.split( "/" )[0] : "" )
```

Comment: What if you have an unknown number of sub-catalogs?

Comment: How do you know which one is the sub catalog and what is not? Can you share the formula for the same?

Comment: That is kinda the problem. I do not know since pathname gives the whole path. I need some way of getting the origin of the project's index file, or base url as it's also called.

Comment: How would a script running on the browser know about the origin of the project's index file? Unless you tell it about that.

Comment: To me it sounds like a thing that should exist since it can get the host of where the script runs.. Or at least Angular should have such a way. Seems silly that you need to hardcode the base url in your code but you can set the base url dynamically when building the project..

Comment: How would you infer from a string `https://sites.dev.myApp.com/ui2/dashboard/events` that its context is `https://sites.dev.myApp.com/ui2/`?

Comment: Well if I knew that we wouldn't be having this discussion :D

Comment: I don't think you can do it from the browser without getting this specific info from the server.